# Do any ancient sources describe Set as a mortal? And could Set be Sekhen?

Tags: egyptian, mythohistory, history, bible, demi-gods

**Set**

> Set /sɛt/ or Seth /sɛθ/ (Egyptian: stẖ;[a]) is a god of deserts, storms, disorder, violence, and foreigners in ancient Egyptian religion.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity)) In Ancient Greek, the god's name is given as Sēth (Σήθ). Set had a positive role where he accompanies Ra on his solar boat to repel Apep, the serpent of Chaos.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity)) Set had a vital role as a reconciled combatant.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity)) He was lord of the red (desert) land, where he was the balance to Horus' role as lord of the black (soil) land.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity))
> [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(deity))

**Sekhen**

> Ka, also (alternatively) Sekhen,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka_(pharaoh)) was a Predynastic pharaoh of Upper Egypt belonging to Dynasty 0. He probably reigned during the first half of the 32nd century BC. The length of his reign is unknown.
> [Sekhen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka_(pharaoh))

Now in legend, Horus, is supposed to be Sets nephew.
It just so happens that Horus-Aha is predecessed by Narmer, who is predecessed by Sekhen.

**Narmer**

> Predecessor Ka (Sekhen) Successor  Hor-Aha
> [Narmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narmer)

**Summary**

So we have a legend which states that Set went to war with his nephew Horus, over kingship of Egypt.

We also have a real pre-dynastic pharoah, from dynasty 0, named Sekhen, who appears to have a nephew or relation named Horus-Aha.

So could this account for Sekhen being Set? And are there any ancient sources which describe Set as a mortal?

Answer (score 4):

Seth and Sekhen/Ka are completely unrelated names & meanings. Below are the names of *Ka* (left) and his queen *Ha* (right):

[image]

There are also inscriptions presenting an upright serekh with an upside-down *Ka*-symbol inside, which renders "Sekhen".

*Sekhen* means "to grasp, to hold". *Ka* means "to embrace". Because the up/down reading of the name is so uncertain, Egyptologists prefer a neutral reading as ‘King Arms’.

Seth, on the other hand, is written in one of these three forms, chronologically ordered:

[image]

Seth's name is thought to have been originally pronounced *sūtiẖ* [ˈsuw.tixʲ] based on spellings of his name in Egyptian hieroglyphs as *stẖ* and *swtẖ*. The Late Egyptian spelling *stš* (set-esh) reflects the palatalization of ẖ while the eventual loss of the final consonant is recorded in spellings like *swt*.

So the likeliness is only apparent in late Egyptian spelling, which is thousands of years after Ka.

Also, I refer to the concept of the Horus name I detailed in an answer to one of your previous questions.